# Repeat Every satement in a loop multiple times Python

Tags: python-3.x

For Example My loop is :

```
    for index in range(0,3):
       statment1  #repeat three times then move to statement 2
       statemen2  #repeat three times then move to statement 3
       statement3 #repeat three times then move to the next line
```

I want Every statment in my loop to be repeated multiple times and then move to the next line, I know this could be a common question but I have not got my answer yet hoping for good now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use a nested for loop? A for loop just like you have for every statement you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nested loops..

```
for index in range(0, 3):
    for index1 in range(0,3):
        print("stmt1")
    for index2 in range(0,3):
        print("stmt2")
    for index3 in range(0,3):
        print("stmt3")
```

But I think this is not you question probably.
You want a single loop and in that single loop each statement should me executed 3-3 times.
Sorry, but For that you have to write 3 loops each for a statement.

```
for index1 in range(0,3):
    print("stmt1")
for index2 in range(0,3):
    print("stmt2")
for index3 in range(0,3):
    print("stmt3")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can use like this using:

    j,k,l=0,0,0
for index in range(0,3*3):
    if j < 3 :
        print("statement1")
        j = j + 1
    elif k < 3 :
        print("statement2")
        k = k + 1
    elif l < 3 :
        print("statement3")
        l = l + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops is what you need

```
for index in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        statement1
    for j in range(3):
        statement2
    for k in range(3):
        statement3
```

Here each internal loop will execute thrice before moving to the next one. The whole set of internal loops will also loop thrice since they're all in one loop. Each statement will execute 9 times. If you want to loop each statement thrice only then you need 3 separate loops.